# The easiest way to communicate a Python script to supervisors?

Tags: python, markdown

I finished my first draft-computation and was wondering how to most effectively communicate the code to non-Python users. I was thinking of a HTML or PDF file (maybe in *jupyter notebook* style) that allows to neatly show the code with it's rendered outputs, as well as some text to thoroughly explain what is done in every step. I saw that **Markdown** seems to be a package for that purpose, but I was wondering whether there is a easier way to go about it, before I read into the package specific syntax.

Comment: I've had good results creating and presenting Jupyter notebooks to communicate the intent and flow of code to non-programmers.

Comment: @cco I do think that would work, but I would like to be able to send them a file which does not require any specific knowledge rather than expecting them to learn the basics of Jupyter notebooks

Comment: IMHO this is a bit unclear. Do you want to explain the actual code, or the algorithm, or what the program is doing? Is the reader another programmer who just happens to not know Python, or a "code-illiterate"? For a few short lines, a notebook or similar might work, but for larger projects, you might consider using UML instead, abstracting from the actual code. Similarly, if you want to present an algorithm, consider using pseudo code, or just naming the algorithm, if it's some standard one.

Comment: @tobias_k I would like to easily communicate code and algorithms. I think they might have some Stata or R knowledge but I would prefer to make it as easy as possible and assume they do not have any programming knowledge. As of now, it is not a long script (around 100 lines). Given the co-authorship of my supervisors I would prefer not to use pseudo-code or abstract too much as after all they need to eventually understand what is done and agree with it. Thanks for the tip with UML

Comment: You might add a bit more information. From your last comment I gather that it is about a simple script, no classes, possibly no custom functions, that runs once, calculates something (statistics, optimization, machine learning, etc.), and stops. In this case, yes, I think a Jupyter/IPython notebook is probably best. Not sure, but that should also have some sort of export/print-to-file functionality.

Comment: You can export a notebook as HTML or PDF for distribution; I work in a Windows environment so, for one project of similar size, I exported to HTML and imported that into Word for distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Sphinx: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/

This is a library which allows you to generate professional looking documentation for your projects. I have used it myself to present my ideas / code to management. The results look very professional and it is pretty easy to use. I would avoid Markdown. Sphinx looks a lot better.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it